# Lazy load and import none compiled JS(X) files at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to lazy load JS-Files from another URL, compile them with babel at runtime which contains JSX and ES6? Of course I want to use ES6 or greater in those files.

I have no option to pre compile anything with babel on a server. 
Everything has to be happen on the client side in the browser.

I tried to use "dynamic-import-node-babel-7" but unfortunately the "import" keyword doesn't support URL's.

Comment: Don't understand it clearly. But are you looking for something like react.lazy(https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html) ? 
It is very recently released and promotes code splitting. 
Not sure what the URL thing means.

Comment: No, or at least you can't perform a production ready solution in this way.